# CUSTOM GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a table
as below

```
Code   ActionType      user  Date
ABC      1             john  2012-09-09
BCD      2             john  2012-09-09
BCD      2             john  2012-10-09
```

I would like to get the code based on the User which  we can get where user='john' and from here based on the code for john i will get code i should get Total 1 occurences and Total 2 occurences in a seperate column and recent date of 2 in a seperate column  .My deisred output is like below

```
Code NumberOf1s     Number of 2s  RECENTDateof1s     RECENTDate of2s
BCD   0              1            NULL                2012-10-09
```

This is the code that has been attempted

```
select code,ActionType,Count(*) as NumbOf1s from Table Where user='john' and               _ActionType in(1,2) 
GROUP BY ActionType,code
```

Kindly help
Thanks

Comment: Hi I have Tried  Group by query like this "select code,ActionType,Count(*) as NumbOf1s
 from 
 Table
 Where user='john'
 and _ActionType in(1,2)
 GROUP BY ActionType,code"  I Get the output as follows

code        ACTIONTYPE NUMbINSTANCES
ABC            1           2
ABC            2           2

But this is not the way i wanted

Comment: If the User is john, how do you get the code BCD from your inputs and not also the code ABC? Apparently one "user" may have more than one code. Then: are the Action Types always 1 or 2? Or are there more action types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE WHEN` in order to consider only certain attributes in an aggregation:

```
select 
  code,
  count(case when actiontype = 1 then 1 end) as numberof1s,
  count(case when actiontype = 2 then 1 end) as numberof2s,
  max(case when actiontype = 1 then thedate end) as recentdateof1s,
  max(case when actiontype = 2 then thedate end) as recentdateof2s
from mytable
where user = 'john'
and actiontype in (1,2)
group by code
order by code;
```

`and actiontype in (1,2)` is optional here, but may speed up the query.